# I can not find my app on the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I would like to understand why I can improve my APP.
I published my APP, but when I go to the PlayStore by the name of "Reforma da Previdencia" my APP does not appear.

But when I type "reformadaprevidencia" my APP appears.

I would like it to appear by typing with space.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual title of your app in the listing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the app name without space matches with your package name so displaying at the top. Since the app is recently published, play store needs to update their search index for the app. In few days, you can get it as per the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Play Store updates their search alghoritms about every two days. Also you can try to put your app name inside the description and add a lot of tags, it's very helpful.